# Sql inline query with parameters. Parameter is not read when the query is executed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a problem with my sql query in c#, basically it's inline query with parameters, but when I run it it tells me that parameter 1 or parameter 2 is not there

here is my query declared on top of the page as public:

```
public const string InsertStmtUsersTable = "insert into Users (username, password, email, userTypeID, memberID, CM7Register) " +
               "Values(@username, @password, @email, @userTypeID, @memberID,@CM7Register ); select @@identity";
```

this is my code for assigning the parameters, I know I am having problem so I am assigning the params twice:

```
Username =(cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = row["username"].ToString()) as string; 
cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = row["username"].ToString();
```

In 1 methopd it calls this query and tries to insert to table, here is the code:

```
Result = Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(con, CommandType.Text,InsertStmtUsersTable));
```

Exact error message is: Must declare the variable '@username'.
Could this code be a problem, because all the previous coding is declared with in this using statement, except declaration of query, here the using statement:

```
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertStmtUsersTable, con))
```

Comment: I don't see how cmd is used in SqlHelper. What is the relationship?

Comment: ya I just realized that sqlhelper code was calling another class for execution, so I changed the code took out the sqlhelper and it's wotking fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just all kinds of ugly. This could be a lot simpler (even though I'm not sure what SqlHelper does:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(InsertStmtUsersTable, conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", userNameString));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", passwordString));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("email", emailString));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("userTypeId", userTypeId));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("memberId", memberId));
    // Rest of your Parameters here

    var result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: The SqlHelper class is a utility class that can be used to execute commands in a SQL Server database. you can more about it here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/941983.aspx