# SQL LIKE query to C# code

Tags: c#, sql

I need to use the following query in my C# code:

```
SELECT AVG(Percent) 
From Table1
Where code Like "Sport" and Year Like"2011" and Sitting Like"June";
```

I did it like this:

```
"SELECT AVG(Percentage) FROM MasterTable WHERE Code LIKE " + comboBoxSubject.Text +
"AND Year LIKE "+dateTimePicker1 +" AND Sitting LIKE June"
```

but i get an exception probably because the parameters are extracted from different controls and are not placed in inverted commas.

Can anyone help me ?

#### ANSWER

That is the query that worked for me:

```
"SELECT AVG(Percent) FROM MasterTable WHERE Code LIKE '" + comboBoxSubject.Text + "' AND Year LIKE '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Year + "' AND Sitting LIKE 'June'"
```

Comment: What exception do you get? And wjhat is dateTimePicker1? Shouldn't you use somthing like dateTimePicker1.Value?

Comment: potential sql inyection detected

Comment: Keep in mind you're leaving yourself wide open for a SQL injection attack with that code, be sure to switch to using `SqlParameter` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=VS.80).aspx) An example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701506/sql-inline-query-with-parameters-parameter-is-not-read-when-the-query-is-execut)

Comment: Your original SQL is also incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you use SQLite, because you don't mention any database. This is how you can avoid SQL injection.

```
var selectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("@SELECT AVG (PERCENT) 
                                       FROM TABLE1
                                       WHERE CODE LIKE @sport AND YEAR LIKE @year AND SITTING LIKE @month");
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sport", sportParameter);
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", yearParameter);
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", monthParameter);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems.

- There's no space after the code value and AND
- There are missing single quotes between values
- The wildcard symbol (%) is missing from the SQL LIKE statements

It depends what kind of project you are working on but often I find it is much easier to spot syntax errors and missing spaces by printing the end query out. For example, below is a console application that does this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string code = "Sport";
    const string year = "2011";
    Console.WriteLine("SELECT AVG(Percentage) FROM MasterTable WHERE Code LIKE '%" + code + "%' AND Year LIKE '%" + year + "%' AND Sitting LIKE '%June%'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `%` and `'` and **please** consider to use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
SELECT AVG(Percentage) FROM MasterTable WHERE (Code LIKE '%' + @text + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for character fields.

```
"SELECT AVG(Percentage) FROM MasterTable WHERE Code LIKE '" + comboBoxSubject.Text +
        "' AND Year LIKE '" + dateTimePicker1 + "' AND Sitting LIKE 'June'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Employee_No, Image, Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name, Suffix, Sex, Birthdate, Contact_No, Address, Username FROM user_tbl WHERE Employee_No LIKE '%" + searchemployeeno + "%' OR Last_Name LIKE '%" + searchemployeeno + "%' ", SQLConn.conn);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.