# Sql select query using like

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to run this code

```
 public long getTopicCountWithTag(String tag)
    {
        long count;
        query = " SELECT count(*) FROM [DB_us2].[dbo].[discns] where tags like '%@tags%'";
        try
        {
            com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tags", tag);
            con.Open();          
            sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            sdr.Read();
            count= sdr.GetInt32(0);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            count = -1;
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

its giving output `0` . So i try figure out what is the problem and run sample query on  management studio but output is different its giving `1`. After trying all permutation combination, i think problem is with this statement `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tags", tag);` might be possible `@tags` is not replaced in query.

Comment: What happens if you temporarily change the query to = @tags, i think the issue is with the '%tags%' syntax, see this question for further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222900/sql-like-query-to-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your query should be

```
string query = "SELECT count(*) FROM [DB_us2].[dbo].[discns] where tags like @tags";
```

And add the wildcard to the parameter

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tags", "%" + tag + "%");
```

Comment: hello kaf your answer is correct but why its not working with above code whats wrong in that.

Comment: unfortunatelli it is a bad advice... what happen if the tag variable takes the following value "'; GO; drop table [DB_us2].[dbo].[discns];"?

Comment: @YaugenVlasau: What is the bad advice here?

Comment: SQL injection is possible

Comment: @YaugenVlasau: The whole idea of parameterised query is to stop sql injection and you are saying otherwise. Values passed through parameters are not evaluate as sql. OP is not running dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
 AddWithValue("@tags", "%" + tag + "%");
```

you have to bring %s inside AddWithValue

Answer (score 0):

```
query = " SELECT count(*) FROM [DB_us2].[dbo].[discns] where tags like '%'+ @tags + '%'";
```

and leave everething as it was.