# How to make value of a column name appear with single apostrophe in sql statement of sql helper inside asp. net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqlhelper

```
 SQLHelper sqhlpr = new SQLHelper();
    sqhlpr.SqlText = "Select StudentName from tblStudentInfo where class=" + NurseryButton.Text;
    DataTable dt = sqhlpr.getDataTable(false);
```

This is my code.Now the result of sqhlpr.sqlText is

```
select StudentName from tblStudentInfo where class= **Nursery**
```

(i.e.NurseryButton.Text=Nursery) but the result that i want is select StudentName from tblStudentInfo where class= '**Nursery'**.How can this be done??? This looks simple but I can't just figure it out...

Comment: I don't know much about this SqlHelper class, so in addition to any answers you get here, you may also want to learn about SQL Injection attacks (which is what your code is vulnerable to). http://colinmackay.co.uk/2005/04/23/sql-injection-attacks-and-some-tips-on-how-to-prevent-them/ If the SQLHelper class supports parameterised queries (and it really should) then use them instead of injecting data into queries.

Comment: Almost *any* data access library you find should have support for *parameters*. You would then make this value a parameter to the SQL, rather than assembling a string by hand. This has the advantage that you're unlikely to create an SQL Injection bug in your program. If you library (not familiar with `SQLHelper`) *doesn't* support parameters, it's a sign to ditch the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Select StudentName from tblStudentInfo where class='" + NurseryButton.Text + "'";
```

But you definitively should not use it that way! ([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Here is a good answer: [Sql inline query with parameters. Parameter is not read when the query is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701506/sql-inline-query-with-parameters-parameter-is-not-read-when-the-query-is-execut)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a string. You do:

```
result = "somestring" + someVariable;
```

Now you want to enclose `someVariable` in sinlge quotes, which is done like this:

```
result = "somestring" + "'" + someVariable + "'";
```

Or shorter:

```
result = "somestring'" + someVariable + "'";
```

However is is worth noting that manually building queries is quite "not done". You should look at tools like parameterized queries or even O/R mappers like Entity Framework.

Comment: thank you everyone for answer and pointing me at the dangers of sql injection

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want:

```
SQLHelper sqhlpr = new SQLHelper();
sqhlpr.SqlText = "Select StudentName from tblStudentInfo where class = '" + NurseryButton.Text + "'";
DataTable dt = sqhlpr.getDataTable(false);
```

You need to think about two more things though:

1. What happens if someone puts an apostrophe in the NurseryButton.Text somehow
2. Will SQLHelper protect you from this sort of thing, or do you need to do it yourself

You should consider parametrized querying or stored procedures in some way to make sure that your input to the database is done safely.