# remove html from sql

Tags: regex, t-sql

I can easily remove html tags from string using regex (<[^>]*>)
but that keeps the text inside the html tags. I have sql insert statement like this :

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `name`, `location`, `description`, `whenadded`, `presentlocation`, `sponsor`, `participant`, `link`, `country`, `proffesion`) VALUES
(1, 'Abdulsalami</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arr', 'Abubakar</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div>', '<P>General Abdulsalam Abubakar (born June 13, 1942) became Nigeria''s eighth military Head of State in 1998, after Ironsi, Gowon, Murtala, Obasanjo, Buhari, Babangida and Abacha, since the country''s independence from Britain in 1960.</P>\r\n                                          </title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div>', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:', '</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div>', 'Male</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div>', '', '</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:', '</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.abdj{position:absolute;clip:rect(452px,auto,auto,452px);}</style><div class=abdj>Depending on which state <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> cap on our money.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div></title><style>.a6js{position:absolute;clip:rect(391px,auto,auto,391px);}</style><div class=a6js>Use more credit sitting <a href=http://kotikpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> it solve their experiences.</div>'),
```

There is one common thing in all my records that it always starts with `</title`  and end with `'`

So I need a regex that will remove every  from `</title`  to `'`  but keeping `'`. Because each column ends is different.

Comment: Are you looking for somethign like [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/qU3cC1/1)?

Answer (score -2):

You can use replace method while inserting like  (run in sqlserver side )

```
declare @str varchar(max)= ( 'Abdulsalami</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arr'', ''Abubakar</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arropaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> making a credit before.</div></title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>')

select REPLACE('abcdefghi','b','f'),
replace( REPLACE(@str,'<title>','''') ,'</title>', '''')
```

In this situation still you can use parameter inline query

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(InsertStmtUsersTable, conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", userNameString));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", passwordString));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("email", emailString));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("userTypeId", userTypeId));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("memberId", memberId));
    // Rest of your Parameters here

    var result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

or

```
using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    dbConn.Open();

    using (SqlTransaction dbTrans = dbConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into [DB].[dbo].[User] ( [Id], [AccountId], [FirstName], [LastName], [JobTitle], [PhoneNumber] ) values ( @id, @accountid, @firstname, @lastname, @jobtitle, @phonenumber );", dbConn))
            {
                dbCommand.Transaction = dbTrans;

                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("id", SqlType.VarChar).Value = id;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("accountid", SqlType.VarChar).Value = accountId;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("firstname", SqlType.VarChar).Value = firstName;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("lastname", SqlType.VarChar).Value = lastName;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("jobtitle", SqlType.VarChar).Value = jobTitle;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("phonenumber", SqlType.VarChar).Value = phoneNumber;

                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            dbTrans.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            dbTrans.Rollback();

            throw; // bubble up the exception and preserve the stack trace
        }
    }

    dbConn.Close();
}
```

[Sql inline query with parameters. Parameter is not read when the query is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701506/sql-inline-query-with-parameters-parameter-is-not-read-when-the-query-is-execut)

[Executing query with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905185/executing-query-with-parameters)

Comment: i am trying to clean my database , your answer will help me prevent it

Comment: Yes always use parameter and pass into value, will prevent sqlinjection. What I still prefer give Sql server procedure for more secure

Comment: Yes thanks , but i need a regex to clean my existing database

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?