# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int in SQL Server query Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I would like to add a record in my database.

There is my code below :

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Insert into RDV (idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire)values('"+comboBox1.Text+"','"+comboBox2.Text+ "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')", con);

    sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Le RDV a été ajouté avec succés !");
}
```

but an error happens:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'John' to data type int.

How should I convert it? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the datatype of each column in table `RDV` ?

Comment: remove single quotes from `'"+comboBox1.Text+"','"+comboBox2.Text+ "','"`  and It should be `comboBox1.SelectedValue`

Comment: @PhamX.Bach **CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RDV] (
    [idRdv]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [objet]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [objectif]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [DateRdv]     DATETIME      NULL,
    [commentaire] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [archive]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [idClient]    INT           NULL,
    [idUser]      INT           NULL,
    [idResultat]  INT           NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_RDV] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idRdv] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([idClient]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([idClient]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([idUser]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([idUser]),**

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to insert `'John'` into the `idUser` field, which is actually an `int`.

You're only getting the text from `combobox1`, whereas you should most likely be getting the value from the selection.

something like `(int)combobox1.SelectedValue` will get the correct value from the ComboBox.

--UPDATE--

Lets for instance say that you're binding your data to the ComboBox as follows:

```
combobox1.DataSource = //whatever your data source is
```

Then you would set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` as follows

```
combobox1.DisplayMember = "username"; //assuming this is the column name
combobox1.ValueMember = "idUser";
```

So now that the combobox has the `ValueMember` attribute set you can then get it as follows

```
int userId = (int)combobox1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: when I do (int)combobox1.Text ,it  underligne it and show me an error **Cannot convert sting to int**

Comment: That's what should happen. It should be `(int)combobox1.Value`, to get value, not the text.

Comment: when i wrote (int)combobox1 then **.** in the list doesn't exist **Value** 
("**Combobox doesn't contain the definition Value**")

Comment: Sorry my bad. `combobox1.SelectedValue`

Comment: Another Error **Specified cast is not valid **

Comment: Ok, what is the ValueMember of combobox1 set as? Is it an int? Is it set at all?

Comment: The value of combobox is a String (Combobox of username ) and in my query IdUser which is int .how can I convert that

Answer (score 0):

For your information about your table `RDV`, the problem is 2 fields: `idUser` and `idClient`. I think you should:

1. Check if your `comboBox1` and `comboBox2` (namming it well please) should have **value** of `idUser` and `idClient` in **int** type (for asp combobox, it has **value** and **text**. **Text** often for display to users and **value** is hidden, can be used for getting **id** like this).
2. Get the right ids by using `comboBox1.SelectedValue` and `comboBox2.SelectedValue` :

   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Insert into RDV(idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire)values("+comboBox1.SelectedValue+","+comboBox2.SelectedValue+ ",'" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')", con);

Just  delete the `'` so it will be `values(1, 4, 'the obj',...)` instead of `values('1', '4', 'the obj',...)`

Comment: The error now was: ** Incorrect Syntaxe to 'John,Lys,'** (john is username, lys name of client)

Comment: First you must bind `idUser` and  `idClient` to your comboboxes **value** not **text**. Then you get the **value** in **int** type like 1, 4,..., not **string** like `john` or `lys`. Second, you should delete all the `single quote '` around the value of combobox like my code in 2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you just check insert statement with direct value into Sqlserver Management Studio that is there any issue. In case you get, change the value, so you have the raw data to insert. Then try to same data via application.

**Step 1**
Try to check insert statement in SSMS with the actual value (Also give single quote only to character datatype)  like

```
Insert into RDV (idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire)

values
( youractualIntValue, youractualIntValue,'youractualStringValue','youractualStringValue','youractualDateTimeValue','youractualStringValue')
```

**Step2** - now use the same key with variable name.

The message shows, that your column is not character datatype i.e. int datatype as per error.

```
//Logic:- Break the code to identify the issue. first individual take variable and pass. Also just debug the variables, one by one and you definately get the error.

int idUser =  Convert.ToInt32( YourControlvalue); //yourcontrolvalue means  combobox or textbox value;
int idClient = Convert.ToInt32( YourControlvalue);
string objet = Convert.ToString( YourControlvalue);
....

Insert into RDV 
(idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire)

values
('" + idUser  + "','" + idClient + "','" + objet + "','" + objectif + "','" + DateRdv + "','" + commentaire + "')", con);
```

[Sql inline query with parameters. Parameter is not read when the query is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701506/sql-inline-query-with-parameters-parameter-is-not-read-when-the-query-is-execut)

Comment: Oh my god !, there is agin an Error **the input string format is incorrect** in the first line  `int idUser = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue); `

Comment: are you check, insert statement with all value in SSMS? then try code

Comment: No,it's not my first insert, I have some records in SSMS

Comment: I execute my INSERT in SSMS and show me the error **Failed converting the varchar value idUser in int data type **

Comment: what is your statement?

Comment: I'am sure that it's wrong but i don't know how to do it:
`Insert into RDV 
(idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire)

values
('" + idUser  + "','" + idClient + "','" + objet + "','" + objectif + "','" + DateRdv + "','" + commentaire + "')`